# Speech recognition error while reading data from an audio file

Tags: python, speech-recognition

This is my code:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
file = sr.AudioFile('E:/music/jack.wav')
with file as source:
    audio_file = r.record(source,duration=20)

print(r.recognize_google(source))
```

I am getting this error:

```
[Running] python -u "e:\Visual studio code\file-1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "e:\Visual studio code\file-1.py", line 8, in <module>

    print(r.recognize_google(source))

  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 822, in recognize_google

    assert isinstance(audio_data, AudioData), "``audio_data`` must be audio data"

AssertionError: ``audio_data`` must be audio data
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

instead of giving `source` to input of `r.rcognize_google` you should give `audio_file` for processing try it once!

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
file = sr.AudioFile('E:/music/jack.wav')
with file as source:
    audio_file = r.record(source,duration=20)

print(r.recognize_google(audio_file))
```