# speech_recognition Throws error ``audio_data`` must be audio data

Tags: python, machine-learning, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, speech-recognition-api

I have a video file and I want to determine the confidence level of the speaker. To perform that at first I am extracting the audio from the video file. Below is the code for that.

```
from moviepy.editor import *    
local_video_path = "Video.mp4"
sound = AudioFileClip(local_video_path)
sound.write_audiofile("sound.wav", 44100, 2, 2000,"pcm_s32le")
```

Above code runs successfully and creates an audio file.

In next step I am using speech_recognition library to determine confidence level of the speaker. I am using following code

```
import speech_recognition as sr

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

audio = sr.AudioFile('sound.wav')
#text = recognizer.recognize_audio(audio)
text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)

confidence = recognizer.confidence()

print(confidence)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
AssertionError: ``audio_data`` must be audio data
```

I even tried different approaches, like the following code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68417492/8777033) URL.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
file = sr.AudioFile('sound.wav')
with file as source:
    audio_file = r.record(source,duration=20)
print(r.recognize_google(audio_file))
```

But above code is giving ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying to use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) for extraction of the audio from the video as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ffmpeg-audio-from-video). This allows to easily try different formats to maybe find a working one. For me 16 bit mono wav extracted using `ffmpeg -i 'Video.mp4' -map 0:a -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 audio.wav` worked.

As a side note, you state you want to "determine the confidence level of the speaker". Afaik the returned confidence symbolizes how likely the transcription is correct, not how confident the speaker is.

Comment: But the issue is not with extracting audio from video. There is no issue in retrieving audio  from video. I have played the audio file using media player. It is just fine. The issue is speech_recognition library. Can you please help me on that.

Comment: From the ValueError I assumed there was a problem with the audio file and therefore suggested to try different formats and such. I did this and for me going to single-channel 16 bit wav worked. I guess if you changed `sound.write_audiofile("sound.wav", 44100, 2, 2000,"pcm_s32le")` to `sound.write_audiofile("sound.wav", 22050, 1, 2000,"pcm_s16le")` it might work,  `ffmpeg -i 'Video.mp4' -map 0:a -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 audio.wav` should do the trick.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/8b07762f80dfec2d34fb4c40b8eddbb7ec503521/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L689) for the `speech_recognition` Python library, this error is given if the audio file that is passed is not an `AudioData` object. Can you please post the object type of the `audio` variable?